# Ansible Yum Module is not working correctly

Tags: mysql, ansible

I am creating an ansible script to automate an LDAP configuration. However, when I do a test run on the script, I always get:

`ERROR: yum is not a legal parameter of an Ansible Play`

I am a bit rusty with using ansible, but I am pretty sure I got this correct (syntactically):

```
---
#Kicks off the installation of Tomcat and MySQL
- name: Connecting to Anssible_centos
  hosts: ansible_centos
  remote_user: root

- name: Retreiving MySQL RPM and Installing
  yum: name=http://dev.sql.com/get/mysql157-community-release-e16-7.noarch.rpm state=present
- debug: var=outputmySql

- name: Disabling MySql57-Community
  yum: disablerepo=mysql57-community
- debug: var=outputDisable

- name: Enabling Mysql56-Community
  yum: enablerepo=mysql56-community
- debug: var=outputEnable

- name: Installing mySql 5.6
  yum: name="mysql-community-server" state=present
- debug: var=install56

- name: Starting MySql 5.6
  service: name=mysqld state=started
- debug: var=serviceStart

- name: Update MySql root password
  mysql_user: name=root host=127.0.0.1 password=codiscope
- debug: var=rootmysql
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is actually a bit off.  Your playbook should look more like this:

```
- name: Connecting to Anssible_centos
  hosts: ansible_centos
  remote_user: root
  tasks:

   - name: Retreiving MySQL RPM and Installing
     yum: name=http://dev.sql.com/get/mysql157-community-release-e16-7.noarch.rpm state=present
```

And if you want to view the results of each task then you want do do something more akin to this:

```
   - name: Retreiving MySQL RPM and Installing
     yum: name=http://dev.sql.com/get/mysql157-community-release-e16-7.noarch.rpm state=present
     register: outputmySql

   - debug: var=outputmySql
```

Comment: Now I get: ERROR: multiple actions specified in task: 'yum' and 'Retreiving MySQL RPM and Installing'

Comment: Can you update your question with an edited copy of your playbook (or at least the first few tasks)? It sounds like you're still having an issue with the indentation/formatting of your playbook.  You might also want to try pasting your entire playbook [here](http://www.yamllint.com/) to perform a quick sanity check of the formatting.

Comment: I apologize, I got it fixed. I forgot to add a dash in front of - name in a few of the tasks